# Assigning path when reading a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
os.path.join("Users",
             "adria",
             "Desktop",
             "pprog.txt")

with open("pprog.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

With this I get an error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pprog.txt'

This works:

```
with open("/Users/adria/Desktop/pprog.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you are constructing with `os.path.join` is only a relative path. To make it absolute you need the path to start with the path separator:

```
path = os.path.join(os.sep,
                    "Users",
                    "adria",
                    "Desktop",
                    "pprog.txt")
```

And then your `open` call needs to actually use the return value of that:

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
```

Comment: That works, thank you!

But, when I do this it does not actually change the file I pointed to?
It creates a new file to the path i assigned and it's not even a txt file.
I dont get that..

Comment: @Slumpe I'm not sure what you mean. If you pass in the "r" flag to `open` then it shouldn't create/change the file at all.

Comment: Damn sorry. I tried to use the write method afterwards with what you showed me.
It works but it just creates a new file instead of writing to "pprog.txt"

Comment: @Slumpe I think you need to open a new question.